# DNS Servers Oracle Linux, VirtualBox

Tags: linux, oracle, dns

I have one virtual machine ( OEL 5.8 ) installed in my virtualbox up and running. I have also configured a DNS Server on that linux.

I cannot ping to the following vip and scan ip-addresses that i had configure in the DNS server from my host machine.

IN NS   racmachine.vmdomain.

racmachine      IN A    192.168.56.101

rac1            IN A    192.168.56.101

rac2            IN A    192.168.56.102

rac1-vip        IN A    192.168.56.111

rac2-vip        IN A    192.168.56.112

rac-scan        IN A    192.168.56.121

rac-scan        IN A    192.168.56.122

rac-scan        IN A    192.168.56.123

I am using host-only network by the way. Anyone knows how to make those vip and scan ip addresses to be 'pingable' from my host machine?

Comment: This appears to be offtopic for SO since it is not about programming. Maybe this question is better suited for superuser.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest have a look at this

[RacAttack Automation](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/RAC_Attack_-_Oracle_Cluster_Database_at_Home/RAC_Attack_Automation)

Is a automated OS deployment for Oracle Rac in Oracle Linux 6

Alvaro.